# Apple Digitally Signed App Limitations

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am about to begin development on a subscription based iOS app but I am confused about the rules that Apple imposes on developes. I have read that developers can digitally sign applications if they don't intend to distribute the app in the app store. This is of interest to me because, among other reasons, I don't want to use Apple Pay for the subscription and the app also requires internet connectivity as it uses a REST API. I have also read that developers can only install their digitally signed app on 100 devices but I am not sure if this is for testing or if this is the total number of devices that can use the app.

Am I interpereting the rules correct? Can a developer deploy a digitally signed application on more than 100 devices? Do digitally signed apps still have to abide by the App Store rules?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: The 100 devices thing is for development testing.  You can get an enterprise license to deploy your apps within your company or you use the app store.  Voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Who are your users?  If you're not going to use the app store, how do you intend to distribute the app?

Comment: @PhillipMills I intend to distribute the app via the marketing website for the app.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for your reply. I don't understand why you consider this to be off topic. This is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

Comment: I don't see how that's an option for iOS distribution.  The three common signing methods are ad hoc (specify device ids), enterprise (distribute inside one organization), and App Store.   There are others -- such as B2B -- that I'm not so familiar with.  Distributing from an independent web site works for Mac, but not iOS.

Comment: @justincdotme I consider it off-topic as it's a question about Apple's development policies and not about programming per se.  It's better asked on the Apple Developer Forums.